# Android ListPreference Default value issue

Tags: android

I have created listpreference to select values but when I want to set default value it says cannot resolve symbol 'Radio1'.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Settings">

        <ListPreference
            android:title="Select radio station"
            android:key="station"
            android:summary="Select radio station you want to listen"
            android:defaultValue="Radio1"
            android:entries="@array/radio_stations"
            android:entryValues="@array/radio_stations"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_radio_white_48dp">
        </ListPreference>

    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

arrays.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="radio_stations">
        <item>Radio1</item>
        <item>Radio2</item>
        <item>Radio3</item>
        <item>Radio4</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```